# DatePicker input field customization in grails

Tags: html, css, grails

I am using datePicker in Grails and I am not able to customize it.

Here is my piece of code,

```
<input type="date" id="dob" name="dob" placeholder="Date">
```

I also tried placeholder but it didn't work.

This is my date field output.(it occurs only in chrome browser)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7wgq.jpg

Desired field output

https://i.stack.imgur.com/brPir.jpg

Comment: where is your code? and how you want to customize datepicker? please explain more.

Comment: input type date behave complete differently on different browser , check other browser and please tell if i could suggest you other date picker code that i want you to try ???

Comment: Not geting what you want but you can check this https://codepen.io/tgrant54/pen/LFblv?editors=1100

Answer (score 0):

In grails, you have multiple choices for this.

**Grails have own date picker tag.**

```
<g:datePicker name="myDate" value="${new Date()}" noSelection="['':'-Choose-']" precision="day"/>
```

You can customize it by following [grails documentation](http://docs.grails.org/3.0.17/ref/Tags/datePicker.html).

Also you can use simply `<input type="date" />`  HTML5 component but it doesn't support in all browsers.

And last one if you want best customized date picker then you can try many third party date picker libraries. e.g. [jQuery Date Picker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)